# Jquery animate not working after addClass

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate, addclass

I have a slide that I want to move down when you click a div in the bottom of it, and back up if you click it again. I'm using this jquery but the second function isn't doing anything.

```
$('#form-toggle').click(function(){
  $('#form-index').animate({
    marginTop:"+300",
  });
  $('#form-toggle').addClass("close-form");
});
$('.close-form').click(function() {
  $('#form-index').animate({
    marginTop:"-300px",
  });
  $('#form-toggle').removeClass('close-form');
});
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but is there a particular reason you have marginTop: "+300" without px on the first one, and not on the second?

Comment: Since you're adding the class, you'll have to delegate the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simplifying it to :

```
var animateOption = {marginTop : -300};
$('#form-toggle').click(function(){
    animateOption.marginTop = -animateOption.marginTop;
  $('#form-index').animate(animateOption);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way for this function to add or subtract 300px from the current margin instead of setting the margin to 300/-300?

Comment: `animateOption.marginTop = -parseInt($('#form-index').css('margin-top'));` `parseInt` is used in case margin is specified in px.

Answer (score 2):

You are dynamically adding a class to the element, and your script is attaching the click event handler before such class is available on the element.

Try delegating the event with the **on** method.

```
$('.parent-class').on('click', '.close-form', function () {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Okay, I changed the second function to use .on and it works the first time, but if you click on #form-toggle again after closing it, it animates down and back up.